# Why is posix_spawn faster when its just a wrapper around fork + exec?

Tags: c, linux, fork, vfork

This is actually a 2 part question.

1. Why is `posix_spawn()` faster than hand written `fork()` + `exec()` when [`posix_spawn()`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/spawni.c) is itself just a wrapper around `fork()` + `exec()`?
2. Why is `posix_spawn()` with `POSIX_SPAWN_USEVFORK` slower than normal hand written `vfork()` + `exec()`?

According to [Ruby posix spawning library](https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn) work it seems like `posix_spawn()` is giving consistent throughput. I read the source code of glibc, but I couldn't find anything obvious that is giving this consistency. Can someone explain it to me?

I made a small [test source file](https://gist.github.com/unmanned-player/2e0d471d4912f68975ff28988416db71) (too big for here, so GitHub), and had it run about 30 times - each time invoking `/bin/true` several times (random number between 1000-10000) - then dividing the total time consumed by total iterations. The results are shown below. Its run on an average Linux Mint desktop with no bells and whistles attached.

I gather the man page considers `vfork()` *to be an architectural blemish*, but for my use cases, its just fine.

[image: Graph of various forking mechanisms]

Here, the `v` prefix is using `vfork()` and `n` prefix is the normal `fork()`.

Comment: The code from the ruby library compares posix_spawn (using vfork) to fork+exec. I suspect it would get more similar results to posix_spawn if using vfork+exec instead.posix_spawn still does a bit more houskeeping than vfork+exec.

Comment: @nos That only partially makes sense for the second part of my question. But I'd really like to know how posix_spawn seems so much better.

Comment: cfork() doesn't copy the memory page table, so when the parent process continues to run, you get a lot less pagefaults.